# Checking between date ranges javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am working on a system at the moment, that has rules based around dates ranges,

a user can submit a form, I need to check to date inputs fit within 1 of 3 dates ranges. Basically the 2 dates need to be within 1 of the 3 following rules,

01/01 - 30/04
01/05 - 30/09
01/10 - 31/12,

I need to workout what month the start date has and what month the end date has basically, and if the end date is outside of the it's range log it.

So basically, if a user submitted 01/01/2017 as a start date and 10/02/2017 as an end date, that would be a valid input, but if a user entered 01/01/2017 as a start date, and 01/06/2017 as end date that would be invalid as the date spans more than one date range.

Is it possible to check this kind of thing with javascript? I have gone through various scenarios, but the ranges in arrays and checking against array values, but I keep getting myself in a mess.

Comment: You've added the momentjs flag, so have a look at their doc, it makes everything easy !
Just create two moments out of your start and end dates (e.g. `var startMoment = moment(start_date)`), then you can get their month by calling `get('month')` on the moment you've just created.

Comment: Since your date ranges span the year, consider writing a function that takes a date as input, and returns 0, 1, or 2 depending on which of your ranges the date is in. Then your task comes down to checking if the function is the same for the start and end dates (at some point you will probably also check start <= end)

Comment: Also looks like you need to check both user dates have the same year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check if a date is in range with getTime()

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kebayowina/edit?js,console)

```js
const isDateInRage = (startDate, endDate) => (dateToCheck) => {
  return dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck <= endDate
}

const isInRangeOne = isDateInRage('2016-01-01', '2016-04-30')

console.log('inRange', isInRangeOne('2016-01-02'))
console.log('outtOfRange', isInRangeOne('2016-07-02'))
```

Comment: Note that `new Date('2016-01-01') will treat the date as UTC, so for users west of Greenwich it will appear to be 2015-12-31. Also, the comparison operators will convert dates to numbers, so there is no need for *getTime*.

Comment: True, but since we just comparing dates with the same string format, it won't be an issue. For more complex logic I'd recommend moment.js in the first place.

Comment: Based on the question, it looks like > should be >=

Comment: Applied the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// parse string 'XX/XX/XXXX' to create date object
function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/');
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daysBetween(date1, date2) {
    return Math.round((parseDate(date1)-parseDate(date2)) / (1000*60*60*24));
}

if(daysBetween('01/01/2017', '01/06/2017') > 1) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: While this is a good approach, you should provide an explanation of how your code fixes the OP's issue. Also, the OP just wants to know if a particular date is in range of some other pair of dates, not the number of days between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function to test the start and end dates for each of the ranges and return true as soon as it fits in one of them. You'll need to correctly parse the strings, and also use the year from either the start or end date and apply it to the ranges.

The function below uses the start date and returns true if the start and end fit in one of the ranges, and false otherwise. If either the supplied start or end dates are invalid, it throws an error.

```js
// Parse date in yyyy-mm-dd format as local date
function parseYMD(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Check start and end date are within one of the valid ranges
var checkInRange = (function () {
  // Bespoke parser
  function parsePart(p, y) {
    p = p.split(/\D/);
    return new Date(y, p[1]-1, p[0]);
  }
  // Valid ranges as d/m, year is taken from start date
  var validRanges = ['01/01 - 30/04','01/05 - 30/09','01/10 - 31/12'];
    
  return function (startDate, endDate) {
    var dStart = parseYMD(startDate);
    var dEnd   = parseYMD(endDate);
    // Throw error if input dates aren't valid
    if (isNaN(dStart) || isNaN(dEnd)) {
      throw new Error('start or end date is invalid')
    }
    var year = dStart.getFullYear();
    // Return true if range is within valid ranges
    return validRanges.some(function(range) {
      var r = range.split(' - ').map(function(s){return parsePart(s, year)});
      return dStart >= r[0] && dEnd <= r[1];
    });
  }
})(); 

// Some tests
[['2016-01-01','2016-04-30'],['2016-03-30','2016-04-30'],['2017-04-30','2017-05-01']].
  forEach(function(dates) {
    console.log('Start and end: ' + dates[0] + ' - ' + dates[1] +
                '\nValid range?: ' + checkInRange(dates[0],dates[1]));
  });
```

Do not use the Date constructor (or Date.parse) to parse strings. Their behaviour is largely implementation dependent. An ISO 8601 format date will be parsed as UTC, which is OK in this context as long as all of the strings are parsed identically, however if they aren't, users will